# Why is a PATH based script chosen before a bash function?

Tags: bash

I am trying to change the behavior of `conda` to first update the `$PATH` to the `miniconda` installation - and then run the command. This is because most of my work with `python` is *not* using the `conda` version and I want to preserve the `PYTHONPATH`.  So here is the bash function:

```
$type conda
conda is a function
conda ()
{
    CONDA=~/miniconda2;
    export PATH=$CONDA/bin:$PATH;
    $CONDA/bin/conda $@
}
```

Is this function getting used?

```
$which conda
/usr/local/bin/conda
```

No it is not. So then - why does `conda` pick up the *former* `$PATH` based executable instead of the bash function?

I am on `macos sierra`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several points:-

- `PATH` will not be updated until the function `conda` is actually called.
- `PATH` will be updated on *every* `conda` call, giving an ever-increasing `PATH`.
- Your call to the `conda` binary contains directory references, and therefore does not use `PATH`, so why try to update it?

If you *do* need to update `PATH` you should check it is necessary, giving something like:

```
CONDA=~/miniconda2
[ ${PATH#*$CONDA/bin} == $PATH ] && export PATH=$CONDA/bin:$PATH
conda () { $CONDA/bin/conda $@; }
```

In other words, run the environment-setting commands *before* the `conda()` declaration, rather than within it.

Comment: your first  point is the important one I missed: the ever increasing path was realized but acceptable.

Comment: @javadba - I just realised that, once you run the two environment-setting commands, the function declaration becomes unnecessary, since the `~/miniconda2` version will be invoked anyway. To be absolutely sure of this, change the second line to `[ ${PATH#$CONDA/bin} == $PATH ] && export PATH=$CONDA/bin:$PATH`, ie update `PATH` only if `$CONDA/bin` is not at the head of the list; or you could compare the return of `which conda`.

Answer (score 2):

AFH's answer is correct, but doesn't answer the direct question. The direct answer is: a PATH based script *is not* chosen before a bash function. The `which` command does not tell you what the shell will execute, it *just* searches the `PATH`. `type` (which is a bash builtin) is the one that tells you what'll actually happen when you type in that command. Here's a quick demo:

```
$ type democmd
democmd is a function
democmd () 
{ 
    echo "This is the democmd *function*."
}
$ which democmd
/usr/local/bin/democmd
$ more /usr/local/bin/democmd
#!/bin/bash
echo "This is the democmd *script*, running from /usr/local/bin"
$ democmd
This is the democmd *function*.
$ command democmd    # The "command" command ignores aliases and functions
This is the democmd *script*, running from /usr/local/bin
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that I'd overlooked part of the question, and for filling in what I omitted.